# Not able to access http url using java in app engine

Tags: java, security, url

I have written simple java code to access url www.nseindia.com
In my local and on Google appengine ,it throws exception
With below message
Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://www.nseindia.com/" on this server.
Reference #18.9420b07b.1335496818.23b178f
Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://www.nseindia.com/" on this server.
Reference #18.9420b07b.1335496818.23b178f

I am using App Engine SDK 1.5,JRE 1.6
Please advise

Answer (score 0):

this is because GAE doesnt allow some classes like file io or networking, check out this guide to achieve what you are looking for.

[URL fetch](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/overview)

and this is the list of allowed classes [class whitelist](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist)

Comment: I have used below code from Documentation.
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/atom.xml");             
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));             
String line;              
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
}

 I am not writing into any files.
Still it says access deined in local and GEA server

Comment: check if what you're trying to do is not a paid service or it requires extra config in your html file

Comment: this is just any url,checked the Quots on URL Fectch looks Okey.