# Accessing URL on google app engine

Tags: java, security, google-app-engine, url

I have written a servlet on app engine to call URL from nseindia.com, please refer below snippet of code

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("https://nseindia.com");
    System.out.println("URL - " + url.toString());
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    //StringBuffer json = new StringBuffer();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            //json.append(line);
        System.out.println("line-" + line);
    }
    reader.close();

    }
```

This code works fine when i call from main method, but same thing is not working on app engine (throws below exception)

```html
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>

You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;nseindia&#46;com&#47;" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;64d70b17&#46;1494045584&#46;4ed8f9c1
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Please tell me do i need to set any attribute access this URL, i have to access this URL because my application will not work if i don't get the data from here. 
I have followed the coding as mentioned in [URL fetch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/issue-requests)

There is a similar question [here with no answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344611/not-able-to-access-http-url-using-java-in-app-engine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make a `https` request. You have to specifically pass `FetchOptions` as mentioned in their docs for issuing https requests [0]

Something along these lines should work -

```
URLFetchService fetcher = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();
FetchOptions fetchOptions = FetchOptions.Builder.validateCertificate();
HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(url, HTTPMethod.GET, fetchOptions);
request.setHeader(new HTTPHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"));
HTTPResponse response = fetcher.fetch(request);
```

[0] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/issue-requests#issuing_an_https_request

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, it is still giving 403 for the above code with http/https. :(

Comment: @SunilRk It appears it expects a valid user agent. I've updated the answer and I was successfully able to fetch the website. Let me know if you're still having issues.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks a lot:) Little modification worked like a charm :)

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear!